# hadoop reduce side join of context and another input file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have the following simple reducer:

```
int i = 0;
int numPurchases = 0;
IntWritable count = new IntWritable();

@Override
protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    i = 0;
    for (IntWritable val : values) {
        i = i + Integer.parseInt(val.toString());
        numPurchases ++;
    }
    count.set(i/numPurchases);
    numPurchases =0;
    context.write (key, count);
}
```

The above simply returns the following to the output:

`customerId  |  avgPurchasePrice`

The reducer above got its data from a file `File1`.
Two questions:

1) Can I add the number of purchases `numPurchases` to the output file? Any pointers on how to achieve that would be greatly appreciated

2) Now I have another file `File2`. File2 has basically the following:

`customerId  | customerName |  customerPhone  | customerAddress`.

Can I do a reducer side join so that the output file would have the following format:

`customerId  |  name  |  phone  |  avgPurchasePrice  |  totalPurchases`?

If so any examples out there I can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this,

create two custom types. **CustomerKey** and **PurchaseSummary**

1)**CustomerKey** : Having customerID,name and phone number. This should implement `WritableComparable`

- Implement the `public int compareTo` such that it uses customerID for comparison.
- Override the toString method.

2)**PurchaseSummary** : Having avgPurchasePrice and totalPurchases. You can implement `Writable`

- override the toString method

I am assuming number totalPurchases is the sum of number of entries for each customer.

- in mapper read the text and create an instance of your CustomerKey. The value should be the same what you are doing now
- in reducer create an instance of PurchaseSummary and fill its values accordingly.

Comment: This seems to make sense but the data is in two files... Should your solution use multipleInputs or read files separately, somehow? I am trying to put everything together before marking as answer...

Comment: you can put all the files in a hdfs dir and pass this dir as argument to the program. FileInputFormat processes all the files present in the input dir.

Comment: That part I do know. But then how will the mapper know which file to access and how will the reducer know what to join....

Comment: I didn't notice the part of two different files, You can use MultipleInputs for this and have two mappers one for each file

Comment: And to join into one?

Comment: as you mentioned you can do reducer side join since the key is going to be same. For a customer you will be getting two types of values i suppose. one type from file1 and the other type from file2. write some logic to aggregate the result of these two and emit.